# How can I create a web form that displays and accepts Tamil language?

Tags: php

I am developing a PHP Application that needs to display and accept content written in tamil. 
For example "login" should be written in tamil on the form.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strategy for website with international strings](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/188137/strategy-for-website-with-international-strings)

Answer (score 8):

If you want to display tamil characters on a web page, be it in PHP or any other web technology, you have to indicate to the browser that the page is written in UTF-8.

Also, "[how to create web sites in indian languages?](http://www.azhagi.com/free1.html)" might help you as it gives why and how you have to do it.

In short:

1. Make sure to save your PHP file in UTF-8.
2. Indicate to the browser that the page should be viewed in UTF-8 by adding the following meta to the page: `<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`
3. You have to configure your web application to serve UTF-8 content. As such, The **HTTP Content-Type header** should look like so: `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`

I'm not a PHP programmer at all, but you should check out [How to display unicode data in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2446778/866172), this should help you a lot.

Comment: To put it more generally - any encoding that encodes a character set that contains the characters to be used. For tamil UTF-8/16/32 or [TSCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TSCII). UTF-8 is the most practical of course.

Comment: very good point!

Comment: Great answer.  Also, your database must be set up to use UTF-8.  Some details that may help: http://glenpeterson.blogspot.com/search/label/UTF-8

Answer (score 2):

Save the files in UTF-8 if using a editor like Editplus or eclipse you can google how to

Use a multipart form with UTF encoding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075513/php-parsing-multipart-form-data

In your persistance / data base layer set up the tables to accept UTF-8 and your good to go. If using My SQL its usually on by default for varchar

Comment: oh yeah : Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 is very important.

Comment: * we had to save all files includes etc in UTF-8 too.